# Using ForAll and Patch to either UPDATE or INSERT a record in PowerApp

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I have a gallery of created data that I want to Patch to the database. The problem is, some records may already exist in the database, and it that's the case, I just simply want to update the data that's there. If the record isn't there, I want to create it.

I set up a ForAll function that can use a Collection to determine if the data exists by using CountRows against the parameters required. This works fine.

I've also set up the Patch code for if the record doesn't exist, which also works fine. To check the data in the table, I'm using ThisRecord.Date for example.

The issue is, whilst all the data inserts fine, it doesn't seem to update anything. I think the issue is I'm viewing the ForAll function like a loop - so expecting it to iterate through each record in the Gallery and check the database to make the decision to Update or Insert, and I don't believe the ForAll function works that way.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Depends on how the ForAll is used, so current code would be helpful, from the docs it does seem there are several options to iterate each item, also what is the DB? SQL Server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-forall